# margin:0 auto; does not work

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I know this Question was asked a few times, but it does not work with my example :(

Here is my code

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="welcome">
    <h1>h1</h1>
    <h3>h3</h3>
    <small>small</small>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-image:url('sitebackground.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.welcome{
   display: block;
   left: 10%; 
   width: 80%;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Pierce `left` attribute is useless without `position` attribute anyway so that dont matter. @ciaodarwin it centres for me, or are you trying to centre the text with div.welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove left: 100% as Pierce McGeough suggests. I created a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tangibleJ/JmsK7/) to demonstrate. I also added a background-color to demonstrate the width of 80% and centered position.

```
.welcome{
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

In case you are also trying to get rid of the top margin, that one is coming from the h1. So add the following css:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0; /* or just margin-top: 0; */
}
```